# How to populate timezones table in mariadb

Tags: mariadb

I am using this function in maria db it returns null.
`SELECT CONVERT_TZ('2016-01-01 12:00:00','GMT','Africa/Johannesburg');`
I searched on google it tells me to populate tables in maria db. But I do not know how to populate timezones table in maria db I see maria db documentation but it not help me.
Please help me to populate table.

Answer (score 0):

I assume the MariaDB documentation you found is: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/time-zones/#mysql-time-zone-tables. Referenced there are the bottom is:

There is a zip file containing an updated timezone SQL information on https://mirror.mariadb.org/zoneinfo/ than can be imported.

On Linux and Unix based systems the `/usr/share/zoneinfo` path contains all this information and the following will import this into the time zone tables:

```
mariadb-tzinfo-to-sql /usr/share/zoneinfo | mariadb -u root -p  mysql
```

Comment: How about a MariaDB Collective?